# How to add the ncurses.h to a C++ program compiled on gcc?

Tags: gcc, c++, ncurses

I am totally new to C++ programming on gcc. I wanted to add color to my text on the output on the console. Since there is no conio.h on linux, I researched and found that ncurses.h could do the trick. Now the only problem is that I do not know how to download it and then add the library. Can someone please describe the method?

Also, if anybody can describe whether ncurses.h is a better option than curses.h or if I am completely wrong in using curses.h?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

on ubuntu:

install ncurses library (packages for developers has "-dev" postfix)

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

for each package, in `/usr/share/doc/{package name}/` you can find documentation.

Open this URL `file:///usr/share/doc/libncurses5-dev/html/index.html` in your browser.

Have fun.

Comment: In the unlikely event that the documentation for `ncurses` doesn't prove sufficiently helpful, you can always pick up a copy of Dan Gookin's _[Programmer's Guide to nCurses](https://www.amazon.com/Programmers-Guide-NCurses-Dan-Gookin/dp/0470107596)_